# How do I achieve horizontally aligned, gap-less, and centered div elements in container div

Tags: html, css

I have 3 elements that I would like to align horizontally, without gaps in between, and centered. I've accomplished lining them up horizontally and equally spaced, but want the touching, ie, to not have white space between them but to also take up 100% width of the page. This is generic html but applies to what I've done on my actual page:

CSS:

```
.content{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color:white;
    text-align: justify;


}
.content .featureitem{

   height: 100%;
    width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:bisque;
    margin: 0;


}

.content:after{
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="featureitem"></div>
    <div class="featureitem"></div> 
    <div class="featureitem"></div> 
</div>
```

I've tried using display:flex, but that leaves a gap on the right hand side. I want to achieve a row of 3 divs, that span 100% of the width with no gaps in between.

Comment: First issue is: 1/3 is not 33%, but 33.33333...%. Second: `inline-block` must have space around, so use `display: block; float: left` instead.

Comment: I'm using chrome and [this code pen link](http://codepen.io/jhechtf/pen/wGVjeM?editors=0100) shows 3 divs with no space between them. They are covering up the entire row since you can't see any black lines.

Comment: @Jhecht, but you did not use 33% width.

Comment: my bad, had deleted something right after it got shared ( I was fiddling with it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by removing the `display: inline-block` and adding `float: left`. Also you should consider calculating your width, since `3*33% != 100%`:

```
.content .featureitem{ 
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100%/3);
    //display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    background-color:bisque;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8g47dxzq/)

Comment: Should there be space around calc operators?

Comment: If you meant the space between `100%` and `/`, then no (doesn't make a difference)

Comment: Please note: The + and - operators must always be surrounded by whitespace, so it is always better to put spaces and you cannot miss.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to stick with `display: inline-block;` for layout, there are a number of ways to fight the [space between inline block elements](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/). There a number of good solutions in the CSS Tricks article. I typically use the negative margin option (it hasn't come back to bite me in a major way yet):

```
nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
}
```

or

```
nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -2px;
  margin-left: -2px;
}
```

If you're open to another layout, you can use flexbox, or even center a float-based layout with a parent `<div>`, if that makes sense.

Comment: you misspelled `margin-left`, just a heads up

Answer (score 1):

if you use `inline-block` elements and have indentation in the HTML code, there will be a white space in between each of them.*(just like the one you leave  in between words)*

you may avoid any gap in html or use  `display : flex` or table layout.

You can use HTML comment `<!-- comment -->`to erase the gap

```css
.content{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color:white;
    text-align: justify;


}
.content .featureitem{

   height: 100%;
    width: 33.33%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:bisque;
    margin: 0;


}

.content:after{
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="featureitem"></div><!--
    --><div class="featureitem"></div><!--
    --><div class="featureitem"></div> 
</div>
```

or table/table-cell display

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: justify;
  display: table;
}
.content .featureitem {
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: bisque;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="featureitem"></div>
  <div class="featureitem"></div>
  <div class="featureitem"></div>
</div>
```

or display:flex and flex:1

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: justify;
  display: flex;
}
.content .featureitem {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: bisque;
}
.content:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="featureitem"></div>
  <div class="featureitem"></div>
  <div class="featureitem"></div>
</div>
```